# How do I disable support for reordering by dragging and dropping within QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have enabled dragging and dropping within a [QTreeWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTreeWidget.html), but I don't want to allow reordering of items by dragging them around. How do I disable such reordering?

I've basically enabled dragging and dropping within the QTreeWidget like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class _TreeWidget(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like reordering by dragging is disabled implicitly when enabling sorting (via [setSortingEnabled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtreeview.html#sortingEnabled-prop)), so this is at least a partial solution. In my case user sorting should be enabled anyway, so it's good enough for me.